# print partial associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays

The following lists the whole vector:

```
foreach($vector as $key=>$value)
{
echo "Key=" . $key . ", Value=" . $value;
echo "<br>";
}
```

How can I obtain, say, the first ten elements from such an associative array such that all the information of the keys and the values remain intact?

I have tried all sorts of little things I have picked up but I just can't get this to work. I assume I am missing something rather simple!

Comment: How is simply echo'ing out the data in any way not keeping it intact?

Comment: you can use `array_slice` http://php.net/array_slice

Comment: @Fluffeh I tried `echo $vector[1]` but it gives me no output?

Comment: @JunaidAtique `array_slice` does indeed do the job I was looking for. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$count = 0;
foreach($vector as $key=>$value)
{
 echo "Key=" . $key . ", Value=" . $value;
 echo "<br>";
 if(++$count == 10)
 break;
}
```

Comment: I copied/pasted this and tried: but it gave me a parse error.

Comment: have you added `;` after `break` ?